# jquery .sort case sensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to sort an array with strings alphabetically (regardless of capital or lower letters). 
For example b, C, A should become A, b, C. < br />
But since .sort is case sensitive (something with ASCII) it becomes A, C, b < br />

```
var myArray = [ 'b', 'A', 'C' ];
myArray.sort();
console.log(myArray);
```

Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x93N8/

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to lowercase the strings when comparing them in the sort function like this:

```
var myArray = [ 'b', 'A', 'C' ];
myArray.sort(function(a,b){
    var alc = a.toLowerCase(), blc = b.toLowerCase();
    return alc > blc ? 1 : alc < blc ? -1 : 0;
});
```

To quote the ECMAScript 5 spec:

> 15.4.4.11 Array.prototype.sort (comparefn)
>   The elements of this array are sorted. The sort is not necessarily stable (that is, elements that
>   compare equal  do not necessarily remain in their original order). If
>   comparefn is not undefined, it should be a function that  accepts two
>   arguments x and y and returns a negative value if x < y, zero if x =
>   y, or a positive value if x > y.

You can find the full ECMAScript spec here: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf and read all about sorting on page 140.

You can also read about the sort method here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

You can see the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/x93N8/2/

Answer (score 3):

You can do this :

```
myArray.sort(function(a,b){
   a = a.toLowerCase(); b = b.toLowerCase();
   return a>b ? 1 : a==b ? 0 : -1;
});
```

Comment: This goes against the specs which states that a sort function should return a greater than zero values, a zero value or a less than zero value depending on the comparison. IMO we shouldn't advice people to build lazy implementations like this.

Comment: @MartinJespersen: +1 to your comment. (I had also quoted some of the spec here, but apparently you did the same in your answer below, so +1 to your answer as well :) )

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray.sort(
    function(a, b) {
    if (a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    if (a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase()) return 1;
    return 0;
    }
);
```

lease note that I originally wrote this to illustrate the technique rather than having performance in mind. Please also refer to answer @Ivan Krechetov for a more compact solution.